# NiFi processor to search and replace multiple words in a txt file

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I have txt file which I am reading using FetchSFTP in NiFi. Also, I have key and values in json format, as shown below received after REST call and JoltTransformJSON:

```
[{
    "Key": "k2s2e2",
    "Value": "Ottawa"
}, {
    "Key": "60601",
    "Value": "Chicago"
}, {
    "Key": "",
    "Value": "London"
}]
```

How can I replace all the occurrences of matching key from above to its value in txt file.

Example: abc.txt

```
000 apple stocks at k2s2e2 888
9000 samsung stocks at 60601 9990377
88 nokia devivces at 78889 790888071 hgj 7
```

Output:

```
000 apple stocks at Ottawa 888
9000 samsung stocks at Chicago 9990377
88 nokia devivces at 78889 790888071 hgj 7
```

My attempt using ExecuteGroovyScript:

```
import static groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

class KeyValue{
    String key
    String value
}

private findAndReplace(KeyValueList) {
    def response
    KeyValueList.each {
    def srcExp = it.key
    def replaceText = it.value

   def inputFilepath = "C:\\Project\\abc.txt"
    def outputFilepath = "C:\\Project\\abc_output.txt"
    
    new File(outputFilepath).withWriter { w ->
        new File(inputFilepath).eachLine { line ->
          w << line.replaceAll(srcExp , replaceText ) << '\n'
        }
      response = w
      }
new File(inputFilepath).text= new File(outputFilepath).text
}
return response;
}

def flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return

def KeyValueList = []
//try {
        def is = flowFile.read().withReader("UTF-8"){ new JsonSlurper().parse(it) }
        is.each {
               if(it.Key != "") {
                    KeyValue keyValue = new KeyValue(key:it.Key,value:it.Value)
                    KeyValueList.add(keyValue)
                 }
            }
          def retval =  findAndReplace(KeyValueList)
          flowFile = session.write(flowFile, {outputStream ->
               outputStream.write(retval.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
           } as OutputStreamCallback)
    
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
//}catch(Exception e) {
 //   log.info(e.getMessage())
//    REL_FAILURE << flowFile
//}
```

Comment: Looks like you need a http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.LookupRecord/ but your text file does not look like structured...

Comment: @daggett Yes it is not structured. Basically I will have to go through entire txt file and look for first Key, if found then replace with value and then look for second Key in txt file

Comment: If I read the content of txt file using ExecuteGroovyScript. In groovy script read txt file line by line and then look for key in first line and then second line and so on. But, how do i pass contents of both txt file and json key value to groovy script.

Comment: I think you need use `SimpleKeyValueLookupService` to map keys between both the files and fetch the value

Comment: With groovy script it depends on how json correlates to txt. Is there a json for each txt? Or json could be cached for a while?

Comment: @daggett I have only one text file which I am retrieving using FetchSFTP . Also I have Json array retrieved from REST call. I can store json in database or some file if needed and later retrieve when searching is needed

Comment: Then use this simplest way - file to store json. And read it when processing txt using script.

Comment: @daggett I have made an attempt to get the json content from the flow file and store it in a list. Then read the file and replaceAll key with value. But my ExecuteGroovyScript is not returning any output, is there some issue with script. Can you please verify.

Comment: you are reading for each replacement key source file again. so each time you are loosing previous result. and the last key is empty - so it replaces nothing.

Comment: @daggett if I change the logic inputFilepath = outputFilepath say by introducing third variable; so that I don't loose previous result remaining logic is fine and it should work right? But, right now I am not getting any response not even the original flow file.

Comment: any error message ? maybe file goes to error output?

Comment: @daggett Yes the file was going to error output, but no error message even in logs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239406/discussion-between-daggett-and-likegreen).

Comment: remove try-catch from your code to let nifi process it

Comment: @daggett I have joined chat discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not a response to your question. just a try to fix your code.

if i understand correctly you are trying to

- read json from flowfile
- read text from some file path
- write text with replacement to flowfile

code for `ExecuteGroovyScript` processor

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def ff = session.get()
if(!ff) return

ff.write{rawIn, rawOut->
    def keyValueList = rawIn.withReader("UTF-8"){ new JsonSlurper().parse(it) }

    new File('c:/Project/abc.txt').withReader("UTF-8"){reader->
        rawOut.withWriter("UTF-8"){writer->
            reader.eachLine{line->
               keyValueList.each{ if(it.Key) line = line.replaceAll(it.Key, it.Value) }
               writer << line << '\n'
            }
        }
    }
}

REL_SUCCESS << ff
```

don't have time to test it...

Comment: In the example above can we read .txt file from sftp server say using JSch, and SFTP.  Only issue here is password is hardcoded. JSch ssh = new JSch()
Session sess = ssh.getSession "user", "server.domain.com", 22
sess.with {
setConfig config
setPassword "somecomplicatedpassword"
connect()
Channel chan = openChannel "sftp"
chan.connect()